# Is there a way to identify if a for loop is done iterating?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am relatively new to coding and I keep running into this problem. Your help would be much appreciated:

I am looping over instances and append them to a list if the values are not 'nan'. Now, as soon as there are 10 values in the list, I want it to stop appending (I don't need the items that exceed 10) and calculate the average of the list - everything works well up to this point with the following code:

```
for x in someData:
   if x != 'nan':
   lst.append(x)
                
   if len(lst) == 10:
      avg = round(sum(lst)/len(last),2)
      break
```

Sometimes though, the instances I loop over won't even get to the admired length of 10, in which case my code does not continue.

I have tried to just calculate the average of the list right after the loop, but then it calculates it for every iteration where it does not have a length of 10 yet. I have also thought of using a while loop, but I can't figure out how to arrange it.

Is there any way to tell if the loop is done iterating and continue with my code?

Comment: You haven't actually shown your loop so we can't say

Comment: You should probably do `if len(lst) == 10: break` and then do the averaging after the loop. Also, what if there are more than 10 elements? Should the others go on another "page", or do you just want the first 10?

Comment: Hey! Can you share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @tobias_k That makes a lot of sense. Seems so obvious now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```py
someData = [ 1, 3, 55, 96, -3, 4, 9, 382, -5, 83, 7, 17, 27 ]

resultList = []
for v in someData:
    resultList.append(v)
    if len(resultList) == 10:
        break
```

So this code processes a maximum of 10 values from some data (here for reasons of simplicity provided in `someData`).

Now we end up with a result list containing a maximum of 10 values. Therefore:

```py
if len(resultList) == 0:
    print("No data!")
else:
    avgVal = sum(resultList) / len(resultList)
    print("Average:", avgVal)
```

If your result list - here: `resultList` - does not receive individual values but data records this basically would not make any difference. Only the specific way in how you would calculate the average would change as you then would need to extract the values you are interested in from the data records first before calculating the average. But in your case it seems that you extract these values anyway.

If your input list would consist of data records things would not be much different either. In this case your processing loop would just be something like this:

```py
resultList = []
for v in someData:
    resultList.append(v["price"])
    if len(resultList) == 10:
        break
```

(In this specific case I would rather use a different name for the variable `v`, maybe something like `record`, but that's a minor details.)

I hope that helps. Feel free to ask I you need more information!